# How to modify and store data, retrieved from an API call, in Firestore correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I retrieve data from an API and want to add new properties(`comments:[], likes:''`, etc.) each of the map. What I tried is that modifying data on UI side, and it didn't effect Firestore side. Even I modify the data on Firestore side by creating new collection it works until I refresh the app. Can you please show me the correct way how to modify and store the data?

```
const newsFromApiRef = firestore().collection('topHeadlines');

//Adding data to firestore

const newsOnFirebase = async () => {
  await getTopHeadlines('us')
    .then((data) => {
      newsFromApiRef
        .doc('testDocUID')
        .set(data)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Data added succesfully');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

//Getting data from firestore, and added new properties

const getFromFirebase = async () => {
  await newsOnFirebase();
  var data;
  await newsFromApiRef
    .doc('testDocUID')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const newData = [];
      querySnapshot.data().articles.forEach((list) => {
        if (list?.comments) {
          newData.push({ ...list });
        } else {
          newData.push({
            ...list,
            comments: [],
          });
        }
      });
      data = {
        articles: [...newData],
        status: querySnapshot.data().status,
        totalResults: querySnapshot.data().totalResults,
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a document's data from Firestore and add new properties to this document, you need to first query for the document (with the `get()` method), as you  do, and then **write back** to Firestore, either with the `update()` or `set()` methods (**which you don't do**).

Since you are using `async/await`, you can do along the following lines:

```
    const snap = await newsFromApiRef.doc('testDocUID').get();
    const docData = snap.data();

    const newData = [];
    docData.articles.forEach((list) => {
      if (list?.comments) {
        newData.push({ ...list });
      } else {
        newData.push({
          ...list,
          comments: [],
        });
      }
    });

    const data = {
      articles: [...newData],
      status: docData.status,
      totalResults: docData.totalResults,
    };
    await newsFromApiRef.doc('testDocUID').update(data);
```

---

Note that since you read **one** document, you are actually getting a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), and not a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), hence the renaming in my anwser.